# React Native Android, why is fragment not visible after a certain offset?

Tags: android, react-native, android-fragments

I have a native Fragment that I'm trying to embed in a React Native application. I've followed the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#integration-with-an-android-fragment-example) to replace the native view with the fragment when it loads. At first, it seemed to work alright but one immediate problem is that it is not respecting the vertical position of the view it is replacing:

[image]

When I tried changing the top position then it started disappearing:

[image]

I can see on the layout inspector the components are still there, however, nothing seems to be rendered

[image]

Any pointers or ideas as to what could be the problem? I'm guessing the native fragment is somehow trying to position itself absolutely to the window but otherwise I don't have any idea what could be the problem